# How to implement OAuth2 Implicit Grant with Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I've been searching the web for a decent tutorial on how to implement OAuth2 implicit grant authorization with Django Rest Framework but couldn't find any resources. Only tutorials for Authorization Code Grant and other types are available or concerns pure Django (not DRF).

How to do it step-by-step? Do I need to reinvent the wheel and code it from scratch?

Comment: How did you fix this. I have the same question.